# Piping requests using gaxios (or axios)

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, node-streams

At present I'm performing the trick of piping a request `req` to a destination url, and piping the response back to `res`, like so:

```
const request = require('request');

const url = 'http://some.url.com' + req.originalUrl;
const destination = request(url);

// pipe req to destination...
const readableA = req.pipe(destination);
readableA.on('end', function () {
    // do optional stuff on end
});

// pipe response to res...
const readableB = readableA.pipe(res);
readableB.on('end', function () {
    // do optional stuff on end
});
```

Since `request` is now officially deprecated (boo hoo), is this trick at all possible using the [gaxios library](https://github.com/googleapis/gaxios)?  I thought that setting `responseType: 'stream'` on the request would do something similar as above, but it doesn't seem to work.

SImilarly, can gaxios be used in the following context:

```
request
.get('https://some.data.com')
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
.pipe(unzipper.Parse())
.on('entry', myEntryHandlerFunction);
```

Comment: I'd say request isn't deprecated (even if the scary warning tries to say so), it's just basically considered... complete. If it works for you, use it.

Comment: @AKX (a) it makes me nervous; (b) on balance I'd prefer to use libraries that are actively maintained and improved; (c) request is a bit outdated internally (even based on what its own creator says); and (d) it doesn't really do async/await without a wrapper around it such as request-promise-native.  So in a way I'm glad to be forced to move away from it.

Comment: Fair enough! I think Gaxios is pretty new and might be missing this, then.

Answer (score 2):

Install gaxios:

`npm install gaxios`

And then use request with the **Readable** type specified and with **responseType** set to **'stream'**.

```
// script.ts

import { request } from 'gaxios';

(await(request<Readable>({
  url: 'https://some.data.com',
  responseType: 'stream'
}))
.data)
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
})
.pipe(unzipper.Parse())
.on('entry', myEntryHandlerFunction);
```

```
// first-example.ts

import { request } from 'gaxios';

// pipe req to destination...
const readableA = (await request<Readable>({
  url: 'http://some.url.com',
  method: 'POST',
  data: req, // suppose `req` is a readable stream
  responseType: 'stream'
})).data;
readableA.on('end', function () {
    // do optional stuff on end
});

// pipe response to res...
const readableB = readableA.pipe(res);
readableB.on('end', function () {
    // do optional stuff on end
});
```

Gaxios is a stable tool and is used in official Google API client libraries. It's based on the stable node-fetch. And it goes with TypeScript definitions out of the box. I switched to it from the deprecated request and from the plain node-fetch library.

Comment: What about the first example, i.e. what is the gaxios equivalent of `req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(res);`?

Comment: @drmrbrewer added the example. Please give it a try.

Comment: The `first-example.ts` isn't working for me.  Get an error calling `await request()`... `GaxiosError: Request failed with status code 404`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you provide `responseType` as `stream` and use `res.data`, you will get a stream which you could pipe like this

```
const {request} = require("gaxios");
const fs = require("fs");
const {createGzip} = require("zlib");
const gzip = createGzip();

(async () => {
  const res = await request({
    "url": "https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/",
    "responseType": "stream"
  });
  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream("./input.json.gz");
  res.data.pipe(gzip).pipe(fileStream);
})();
```

Comment: What about dealing with the first example, which is piping the express request `req` to a destination url?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to basically forward requests from your express server to the clients. This worked for me.

```
import { request } from "gaxios";
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", async (req: any, res: any) => {
  const readableA = (await request({
    url: "https://google.com",
    responseType: "stream",
  })) as any;
  console.log(req, readableA.data);

  const readableB = await readableA.data.pipe(res);
  console.log(res, readableB);
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I imagine more complicated responses from A will require more nuiance in how to pipe it. But then you can probably just interact with `express`'s response object directly and set the appropriate fields.